# Android graph library with range selector that works offline

Tags: android, graph, google-visualization, dygraphs, android-graphview

I am in need of an Android library for plotting graphs with range selectors to choose X axis interval. I've considered the following libraries:

- [GraphView](http://android-graphview.org/)
- [AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org)

GraphView works fine for pinch-zooming and scrolling. But, there are no range selectors in these libraries. Range selectors are two vertical lines that can be dragged to choose X axis range.
This is similar to the *data usage* settings view in Android.

[image: Data usage settings]

The closest I got to it was the following libraries:

- [GoogleChart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter)
- [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail)
- [DyGraphs](http://dygraphs.com/)

But, these are JavaScript libraries that need Internet connection and thus may increase loading time. Please suggest the best method for this.

Comment: Any news meanwhile? I found the [RangeSeekBar library](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/RangeSeekBar).

Comment: Nope. I ended up drawing my own range choosers. Works fine now.              
I edited the GraphView library.

Comment: Is your solution open source?